# How to select the first level of children (li) from ul

Tags: html, css

Given the following structure, I want to select the first level of children (li) from the list (ul), but not the nested list.

```css
ul.list > li {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list" class="list">
   <li>first level</li>
   <li>first level</li>
   <li>
      <h1></h1>       
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>second level</li>
            <li>second level</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

<sup>([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygoh1cee/1/))</sup>

But that selects also the items (li) inside the div.

I want to select the first level of children (li) using only **ONE** **css RULE**. How?

Comment: What that selector does is select the first list-item of EVERY unordered list

Comment: @HTMLNoob - I think that's what the OP is saying his problem is.

Comment: give an id to the ul and use it as selector  `#myUlId>li` or add parent's ul to the selector `body>ul>li`

Comment: What you can do is add an ID attribute to the ul and have the selector (idNAME > li {CSS Content})

Comment: Why don't you give your first `ul` a class and then go `.class li` ?

Comment: lol as you can see @Marco there is a nearly infinite amount of possible solutions.

Comment: Just use a class on the UL and target that...

Comment: @staypuftman id is better, with a class used a couple of times you may run again in the issue ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus - good point.

Comment: tried adding a class and id with no success, the second level items (li) are selected either way. I've added a jsfiddle to illustrate it.

Comment: that is because everything is indeed wrapped inside first-level lis.

Comment: I think some people overlooked that fact, so when you apply something to the first-level lis, you essentially affect everything. Do you have control over the HTML structure? why not just wrap second levels with a UL parent instead of LI parent?

Comment: @Aziz coz semantically speaking you can't do that.

Comment: Another thing is... you've set the background-color or `ul.list > li` -- the inner `<h1></h1><div><ul>...</ul></div>` _**IS**_ a list item in the outermost list, so its background is set because it is a whole _subtree_ of the outer `li`

Answer (score 3):

css does not have a selector that would allow you to specify that all/none of the ancestor elements must match certain critieria (i.e. not be a list), you would need xpath for that.

but what you can do is the following:

```
ul > li {
  // top level list item styles here
}

li ul > li {
  all: initial;
  // nested item styles here
}
```

See [MDN all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) for documentation on resetting styles. You can also selectively [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) specific properties.

Comment: what does `all:initial;` do?

Comment: Notice that this is [not supported by Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: `unset` and `revert` also look cool, but of course _someone_ doesn't support _them_ either.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
ul li div ul li { 
  /* Your styles here to override parent (if they are over 70% the same) */ 
}
```

Comment: While this answer *is* correct, you really should include a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you need to identify your first ul:

```
<ul class="my-list">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li>
      <h1></h1>       
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

then select it with `ul.my-list>li`

Comment: in comments we mostly talked about Id, :)

Comment: tried adding a class and id with no success, the second level items (li) are selected either way. I've added a jsfiddle to illustrate it.

Comment: This does not actually work, you would still have to reset the nested lists.

Comment: @TinyGiant it actually works, https://jsfiddle.net/ygoh1cee/3/ did you realize that childs without background will show background parent ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Yes, so you still have to reset the children, because its parent will have a background colour, and for inherited properties like font colour you will of course still have to reset the children. As I said before, this won't work for what the op is looking for.

Comment: @TinyGiant that's a point of view :) , move those li down : https://jsfiddle.net/ygoh1cee/4/ and then what about givin a bgcolor to body ? Same will happen to those lis, they'll show body background-color.just because they have **no background set**. it is just basic CSS :)  and this is why i say it works ;).  absolute positionning can show it too https://jsfiddle.net/ygoh1cee/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the `<li>`s which contain second-level content and then exclude them from the main CSS query using the `:not` pseudo-class

```css
ul.list > li:not(.level2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
   <li>first level</li>
   <li>first level</li>
   
   <li class="level2"> first level with nested content
      <h1>some title</h1>       
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>second level</li>
            <li>second level</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   
   <li>first level</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have does work, you just need to style the inner `li`'s too, as their background by default is transparent.

Note though, that some properties are inherited by default and will be picked up by the inner `li`'s and needs to be set explicit, like the font color.

```css
ul.list > li li {
  background-color: black;
}

ul.list > li {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}


ul.list2 > li li {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}

ul.list2 > li {
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>Sample 1</div>

<ul id="list" class="list">
   <li>first level</li>
   <li>first level</li>
   <li>
      <h1></h1>       
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>second level</li>
            <li>second level</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li></li>
</ul>

<hr>
<div>Sample 2</div>

<ul id="list2" class="list2">
   <li>first level</li>
   <li>first level</li>
   <li>
      <h1></h1>       
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>second level</li>
            <li>second level</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case the problem is `background-color`, the color is only applied on `.list>li` but childrens show parent's background.

to separate color, you need to add element (for example `div` or `span`)

```css
.list>li>span{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list" class="list">
   <li><span>first level</span></li>
   <li><span>first level</span></li>
   <li>
      <h1></h1>       
      <div>
         <ul>
            <li>second level</li>
            <li>second level</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```